# How can I "mark" a computer in that way I could recognize it later on Python?

Tags: python, detect

I'm searching a way in Python to "mark" a computer, to give the program later an option to recognize the computer.

As you understand I need something that's unique in a computer or make something complex that can't really be manipulated.

**For better understanding:**

I'm actually trying to prevent the usage of a program with the same data (where I will put this unique thing or information about the computer) on another computer.

Comment: It sounds like you're just looking for a license key mechanism.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it inside the post, I need to recognize it without any server (the program should recognize it), as you understood that means that I can't really create a license key mechanism. Also I don't want to limit the access to the program, I want that data wouldn't be duplicated and used in another program using a unique element (all the data will be encrypted using blockchain, so the other side don't really can change it)

Comment: First of: it's impossible to make this work 100% of the cases and against very skilled/invested attackers. Are you okay with this? Second: it's a question of how much effort you want to invest in this. Just enough to foil Timmy-the-Scriptkid or enough to foil skilled pirates with a toolkit full of tricks at their disposal?

Answer (score 2):

It would use a MAC address or Motherboard UUID for this. However, a MAC address is not unique per computer but per network interface. When you change out your network card for example, the MAC address will change. More ways to get a MAC address in Python can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/extracting-mac-address-using-python/#:%7E:text=To%20get%20the%20physical%20address,use%20getmac%20module%20of%20Python.&text=getnode()%20can%20be%20used,using%20the%20uuid1()%20function.).

```
from getmac import get_mac_address as gma

print(gma())
```

Another way to look at this is; what makes a computer unique? Is it the network device, the motherboard, or the hard disk? Or maybe a combination of all? An example of getting the motherboard serial:

```
import os
import sys

os_type = sys.platform.lower()

if os_type.startswith('win'):
    command = "wmic bios get serialnumber"
elif "linux" in os_type:
    command = "hal-get-property --udi /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer --key system.hardware.uuid"
elif "darwin" in os_type:
    command = "ioreg -l | grep IOPlatformSerialNumber"

print(os.popen(command).read())
```

Comment: 1) Computers don't have MAC addresses, network interfaces have MAC addresses; 2) A MAC address is trivial to manipulate

Comment: Beware: [uuid.getnode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.getnode) does return random value if it fails to find hardware address.

Answer (score 0):

You could use computer's MAC address for this:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/extracting-mac-address-using-python/

Comment: 1) Computers don't have MAC addresses, network interfaces have MAC addresses; 2) A MAC address is trivial to manipulate